# Class structure in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

helo,

The app i'm developing has a pivot structure with three pivot items called Calendar, History and Statistics. I have developed the UI using Blend, I wud like to keep the code for the three pivot items in three classes and these three classes need to access the UI elements created in the MainPage. How do i get tht done??

In Qt its enough to add the header file. Is there somethin like tht?? or do i have to inherit from the MainPage class??

Thank you,

Alfah

Answer (score 2):

Consider making 3 separate UserControls and using them on each PivotItem.

Also, the Pivot control is designed to be used to show different views of the same thing. (Consider how email uses diffferent pivot items to filter messages which are unread, urgent, etc.) Your item headers strike me as things which may not be related so you may want to consider your IA.

Comment: thank you matt, 
Im a bit new to C# and silverlight and ofcourse WP. I considered using  pivot cuz all the three shows data in different forms, first in the form of calendar. based on data in the calendar  the history and statistics is generated. Could you explain on creating separate user controls?